# Split string line code without splitting its output

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.7.7.

I have this code:

```
print("Shape:{} - N-Way:{} - Num-shot:{} - Num-query:{} - Epochs:{} - \
        Episodes:{} - Loss_function:'{}' - Accuracy:'{}'".format(image_shape,
        num_way, num_shot, num_query, num_epochs, num_episodes, loss_name,
        accuracy_name))
```

I use `Epochs:{} - \` to avoid the line gets longer than 80 characters. But I get this output:

```
Shape:(200, 200, 1) - N-Way:2 - Num-shot:5 - Num-query:5 - Epochs:2 -          Episodes:10 - Loss_function:'dice_coef_loss' - Accuracy:'accuracy'
```

With this space `Epochs:2 -          Episodes:10 -` between `Epochs` and `Episodes`.

Is there anyway to avoid it? I want this: `Epochs:2 - Episodes:10 -`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
print("Shape:{} - N-Way:{} - Num-shot:{} - Num-query:{} - Epochs:{} - "
      "Episodes:{} - Loss_function:'{}' - Accuracy:'{}'"
      .format(image_shape, num_way, num_shot, num_query, num_epochs,
              num_episodes, loss_name, accuracy_name))
```

It works because in Python, if you have two string literals separated by just whitespace, it's equivalent to just those literals concatenated:

```py
>>> 'asd'   'fgh'
'asdfgh'
```

Answer (score 0):

That extra space is coming from the leading indentation in the next line

```
print("Shape:{} - N-Way:{} - Num-shot:{} - Num-query:{} - Epochs:{} - \
Episodes:{} - Loss_function:'{}' - Accuracy:'{}'".format(image_shape,  
        num_way, num_shot, num_query, num_epochs, num_episodes, loss_name,
        accuracy_name))
```

Trim that & you should get what you want.